# Truncate files names over 255 characters

Tags: bash, sed, fat32

I am trying to copy some files with long file names onto an old Windows XP 32bit FAT32 system and I am getting errors of having too long file names. How could I recursively search through a directory for file names greater than or equal to 255 chars and truncate them as appropriate for a FAT32 filesystem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure `find` can do the whole job, I couldn't quite get the last step so resorted to using some `bash` foo:

```
#/bin/bash

find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex ".{255,}" |
while read filename
do 
    mv -n "$filename" "${filename:0:50}"
done
```

Using `find` to get all the files with filename greater than or equal to 255 characters:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex ".{255,}"`

Truncate those filenames to 50 characters, `-n` do not overwrite an existing file.

`mv -n "$filename" "${filename:0:50}"`

*Note: Can this be with the `-exec` option anyone?*

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
find /path/to/base/dir -type f | \
while read filename
do
    file="${filename%%.*}"
    ext="${filename##*.}"
    if [[ "${#file}" -gt 251 ]]; then
         truncated=$(expr $file 1 251)
         mv "${filename}" "${truncated}"."${ext}"
    fi     
done
```

I actually didn't know how to do this either, but some simple modifications to the [first Google result to "unix truncate file name"](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/40195-how-can-i-truncate-filenmes.html) was sufficient to yield the above solution. Try it yourself first ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `perl` in a terminal :

```
cd /d \path\to\dir
find . -type f |
    perl -F'[/\\]' -lane '
        $f = $F[-1];
        ($ext) = $f =~ /(\.[^.]+)$/;
        delete $F[-1];
        $path = join "/", @F;

        if (length($f) > 255) {
            $c++;
            rename "$path/$f", "$path/truncated_$c$ext"
        }
    '
```

The renamed files will looks like :

```
truncated_1.ext
truncated_2.ext
(...)
```